# Find the probability generating function of $Z=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i.$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, generating-functions

> Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be a sequence of i.i.d Bernoulli random variables
>   with parameter $p$. Let $N$ be a Poisson random variable with with
>   parameter $\lambda$ which is independet of the $X_i.$
>
> **(a)** Find the probability generating function of $Z=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i.$
>
> **(b)** Use (a) to identify the distribution of $Z$.

The pgf of a sum of i.i.d random variables is the product of their respective pgf's so:

$$G_Z(s)=G_{X_1}(s)\cdot G_{X_2}(s)\cdot...\cdot G_{X_N}(s),$$

and sice the $X_{i}$ are Bernoulli distributed with parameter $p$ we have that

$$G_Z(s)=(1-p+ps)^N.$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I can't express my $G_Z(s)$ in terms of a random variable, so what should I do with the $N$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short, it ends up being the expectation of what you have written. But you should start from scratch and try to use the [tower property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) by conditioning on $N$ to formalize all this.

> $$G_Z(s) = E[s^Z] = E[E[s^Z \mid N]] = E[E[s^{X_1} \cdots s^{X_N} \mid N]] = E[(1-p+ps)^N]= e^{\lambda p(s-1)}.$$ It remains to identify the final PGF.

Comment: Based on what you have written, $s^Z = G_{X_1}(s)...G_{X_N}(s).$ Why is this?

Comment: @Parseval *conditioned on $N$* (loosely, "when $N$ is fixed"), you may use the "PGF of sum of independent RVs is product of PGFs" result that you stated

Comment: Yes, but according to the book, that proposition is $$G_Z(s)=G_{X_1}(s)...G_{X_n}(s)$$ and not $$s^Z=G_{X_1}(s)...G_{X_n}(s).$$ I'm probably misunderstanding something.

Comment: Apologies, I see now what you have done. I miss interpreted the "given" oeprator. Thanks!

Comment: @Parseval No, the way I wrote it was a bit misleading, sorry.

Comment: I got stuck on how you got $e^{\lambda p (s-1)}$ from $E[(1-p+ps)^N].$ Using software, the correct answer is $$E[(1-p+ps)^N]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-p+ps)^n\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n}{n!}=e^{\lambda p(s-1)}.$$ I can't find a way to use powerseries to compute the sum. It seems to be a combination of power series for $e^x$ and the geometric, but their combination confuses me. Any idea on how to go about this? If you want to I can make an entirely new thread to only treat the sum.

Comment: @Parseval: Once you take out $e^{-\lambda}$, what remains is a power series of $e^x$ where $x=(1-p+ps)\lambda$. Then it all simplifies to what you want.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer - Ahh, that's neat. Thanks!