# Find the probability distribution of $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$

Tags: probability

I have that $N, X_1, X_2, ...$ are independent random variables. $N$ takes non negative natural values. I also have $$Y=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$$ and I have to find the probability distribution of $Y$ given that $X_i$ all have a Bernoulli distribution $B(1;p)$ and that $N$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$. My work so far is this: 
$$P(Y=y)=P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i=y\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\left(N=n; \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i = y\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(N=n)P\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i = y \right) \quad (1)$$
I have worked out that I can express the probability of a sum of random independent variables as follows:
$$P(X_1+X_2+...+X_n=k)=\\ \sum_{l_1 =0}^k \sum_{l_2=0}^{k-l_1}...\sum_{l_{n-1}=0}^{k-l_1-l_2-...-l_{n-2}}P(X_n=k-l_1-...-l_{n-1})P(X_{n-1}=l_{n-1})...P(X_1=l_1)$$
However I don't think I am able to use this in $(1)$ because since $X_i$ have a Bernoulli distribution, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i = y$ where $y$ must belong to $[0, n]$. Therefore, I don't know how to handle this problem. Could someone please help me?

Comment: The sum of $N$ i.i.d. Bernoulli's is a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3061853/321264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for $k\geq 0$
$$
\begin{align}
P(Y=k)&=\sum_{n=k}^\infty P(Y=k\mid N=n)P(N=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=k}^\infty P\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=k\mid N=n\right)P(N=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=k}^\infty P(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=k)P(N=n)\tag{0}\\
&=\sum_{n=k}^\infty\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{(\lambda(1-p))^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\\
&=\frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda p}
\end{align}
$$
where we used independence of in $(0)$ and the fact that the i.i.d sum of bernoulli(p) random variables are equal in distribution to a binomial random variable in $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The term $P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=y)\right)$ is the same as $P(Z=y)$, where $Z\sim Bin(n,p)$. This has the formula
$$
P(Z=y)={n\choose y}p^y(1-p)^{n-y}
$$
for $y=0,1,...,n$, and $P(Z=y)=0$ otherwise.